# Creating new column based on existing column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame given below like this:

```
ID1    ID2  Yr-Month  Class                   
1      p1   Feb-19   PE5->SC
1      p2   Feb-19   SC
1      p3   Feb-19   EA->PE5
1      p4   Feb-19   EA->PE5->SC
1      p5   Feb-19   PC->PE5->SC
```

I need to create a new column called Final in existing data where if transition is happening from PE5 to SC i.e. PE5->SC in following ways PE5->SC,EA->PE5->SC,PC->PE5->SC Final column value needs to be one else 0 given below is the expected output:

```
ID1    ID2  Yr-Month  Class         Final   
1      p1   Feb-19   PE5->SC         1
1      p2   Feb-19   SC              0
1      p3   Feb-19   EA->PE5         0
1      p4   Feb-19   EA->PE5->SC     1
1      p5   Feb-19   PC->PE5->SC     1
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a 'Final' column of 0s, then use .loc to find the rows where Class contains 'PE5->' using `df['Class'].str.contains('PE5->')`,  and then set the corresponding values in 'Final' to 1

```
df['Final'] = 0
df.loc[df['Class'].str.contains('PE5->'), 'Final'] = 1
```

Output:

```
ID1    ID2  Yr-Month  Class         Final   
1      p1   Feb-19   PE5->SC         1
1      p2   Feb-19   SC              0
1      p3   Feb-19   EA->PE5         0
1      p4   Feb-19   EA->PE5->SC     1
1      p5   Feb-19   PC->PE5->SC     1
```

**EDIT:**
Having seen OP's comment on Jezrael's answer, it appears there was a missing case from the original question. The code to cover the updated case would be:

```
df['Final'] = 0
df.loc[df['Class'].str.contains('PE5->.*SC', regex=True), 'Final'] = 1
```

Output:

```
ID1    ID2  Yr-Month  Class         Final   
1      p1   Feb-19   PE5->SC         1
1      p2   Feb-19   SC              0
1      p3   Feb-19   EA->PE5         0
1      p4   Feb-19   EA->PE5->SC     1
1      p5   Feb-19   PE5->PC->SC     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Test substrings by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and for convert `True/False` to `1/0` convert values to integers:

```
df['Final'] = df['Class'].str.contains('PE5.*SC').astype(int)
```

Alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Final'] = np.where(df['Class'].str.contains('PE5.*SC'), 1, 0)
print (df)
   ID1 ID2 Yr-Month        Class  Final
0    1  p1   Feb-19      PE5->SC      1
1    1  p2   Feb-19           SC      0
2    1  p3   Feb-19      EA->PE5      0
3    1  p4   Feb-19  EA->PE5->SC      1
4    1  p5   Feb-19  PC->PE5->SC      1
```

Comment: If another row contains transition PE5->PC->SC  which is also valid how to modify your code?  I forgot to add this row sample

Comment: @Python_help - If need test any value between `PE5` and `SC` use `PE5.*SC`, solution was changed

Comment: @Python_help You should really edit your question with this updated case, so other answers can also update their answers to what you want, rather than what your question claims you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way would be to use `replace`

```
df['Final'] = df['Class'].replace(['PE5.*SC', '.'], [1, 0], regex=True)
```

Output:

| ID1 | ID2 | Yr-Month | Class | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | Feb-19 | PE5->SC | 1 |
| 1 | p2 | Feb-19 | SC | 0 |
| 1 | p3 | Feb-19 | EA->PE5 | 0 |
| 1 | p4 | Feb-19 | EA->PE5->SC | 1 |
| 1 | p5 | Feb-19 | PC->PE5->SC | 1 |